# One list, two different thank you pages with Mailchimp

Tags: mailchimp

Mailchimp ties each form to one list.

I'd like to have a signup form on Page1.html that sends users to Page1ty.html and another form on Page2.html that sends users to Page2ty.html.  But both forms need to feed users into the same list.  As stated above, this isn't possible using their basic forms.  I would need two list.

Mailchimp says this kind of routing might be possible using their API.  Does any one know how to go about accomplishing the above kind of signups?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would just create custom forms and tie into the MailChimp API, but as of their latest update you'll need to make sure you have administrator privileges.

You include (require) the `MCAPI.class.php` and `config.inc.php` files from their [API downloads](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/), and then write your process (I use `PHP`).

Once you have downloaded the files and set up your 'config.inc.php` file with the proper credentials, (API Key and list ID) you're ready to go.

Here's a sample in `PHP` that subscribes a user to a list, but you'll have to read the API docs to get the exact functionality you're looking for.

```
<?php
session_start();

// ---  Sample fields - depends on your list
$mailChimpTIME = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$mailChimpFirstName = // First Name
$mailChimpLastName = // Last Name
$mailChimpEmailAddress = // Email Address

require_once 'MCAPI.class.php';
require_once 'config.inc.php'; //contains apikey

$api = new MCAPI($apikey);

$merge_vars = array(
'FNAME'=>$mailChimpFirstName, 
'LNAME'=>$mailChimpLastName, 
'EMAIL'=>$mailChimpEmailAddress,
'OPTIN_IP'=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 
'OPTIN_TIME'=>$mailChimpTIME
);

$email_type = 'html';
$double_optin = true;
$update_existing = true;
$replace_interests = false;

// By default this sends a confirmation email - you will not see new members
// until the link contained in it is clicked!
$retval = $api->listSubscribe( $listId, $mailChimpEmailAddress, $merge_vars, $email_type, $double_optin, $update_existing, $replace_interests);

if ($api->errorCode){
    echo "Unable to load listSubscribe()!\n";
    echo "\tCode=".$api->errorCode."\n";
    echo "\tMsg=".$api->errorMessage."\n";
} else {
    // Success
    //echo "Subscribed - look for the confirmation email!\n";
}
?>
```